# Grafana regex to capture two groups

Tags: regex, grafana

I have a list of database names to capture in grafana:

- `db1-producion`
- `db2-production`
- `production-aa-db3-cluster`
- `production-aa-db4-cluster`

So one group is `<name>-<environment>`, another group is `<environment>-aa-<name>-cluster`, but I'd like to exclude the `-cluster` from the second group.

`(.*)-cluster` works and filters the `-cluster` from the second group database names, returning: `production-aa-db3` and `production-aa-db4`

But as soon as I add `(\w*-\w*)|(.*)-cluster`, to capture the first group, it returns: `db1-producion`, `db2-production` and `production-aa`

The result should be:

- `db1-producion`
- `db2-production`
- `production-aa-db3`
- `production-aa-db4`

Any ideas welcome.

Comment: Try swapping the branches ([`(.*)-cluster|(\w*-\w*)`](https://regex101.com/r/peQlhf/1)) or adding some anchors ([`^(\w*-\w*)$|(.*)-cluster$`](https://regex101.com/r/peQlhf/2)). If these options work for you, I'll write an answer explaining.

Comment: As @InSync says, the alternation operator `|` favors the left branch over the right branch when both could match.  Swapping the left and right parts should fix that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem in your approach is that Grafana uses first capturing group as a result<sup>*</sup>, and in expression `(\w*-\w*)|(.*)-cluster` first group matches first two words delimited by dash. (And even if you'd avoid it matching, you'll get an empty variable, since first group wouldn't contain anything)

To remove trailing `-cluster` from your results you can use `(.+?)(-cluster)?`.

Here, first group matches anything, but in a lazy way, thus allowing optional `-cluster` to be matched if it exists in the end of line.

[image]

I assume that anchors `^` and `$` aren't necessary in this case, since Grafana seemingly prefers to match whole input string, but unfortunately I cannot find reference for this behaviour in the documentation.

---

<sup>*</sup> : Unless named group `value` or `text` is present